# NSFetchRequest with NSPredicate not returning any results

Tags: nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

The following NSFetchRequest does not return any results into the array. I suspect something is wrong with the syntax of NSPredicate. Any ideas?

```
    -(NSManagedObject*)requestTheSingleEntity:(NSString *)entityDescription ForWhichIntegerAttribute:(NSString *)attribute isEqualTo:(int)value
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
    NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:entityDescription];

    [request setEntity:e];
    NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ == %@)", attribute, [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
    [request setPredicate:p];

    NSError *er;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&er];
    NSLog(@"the count of results = %d", [results count]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `%K` for attributes, not `%@`:

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@", attribute, [NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
```